# How to get enum value from its index in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

For example I have this enum in ruby-on-rails:

`class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: [ :red, :green, :blue ]
end`

By default, the index should be :red -> 0, :green -> 1, and so on.

I want to get the enum value by index, let's say from index `1`, so the result should be `:green`. Is it possible to do this ?

**Update:**

Pseudo-code example:

`Foo.colors.find_by_index(1)   # returns :green`

Comment: Why don't you define an array instead of enum ?

Comment: What if you have two columns with enums? How do you expect rails to work in that case?

Comment: Send me some sample code including your expected output.

Comment: I also use the enum for Formtastic's select input (e.g. `f.input :color, as: :select, collection: Foo.colors`). The enum index would be the option value, and the enum value itself as the display text/label. Array doesn't fit for this case I think. Another way is using Hash, but here I would like to know if it's possible to get enum value by index.

Comment: What do you mean you want to "get the enum value by index"? Can you provide an example of how you want to do this?

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated the question with pseudo-code example.

Comment: Okay well you could do as `Foo.colors.keys(1) #=> "green"` becuase `colors` is simply a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` so it acts very similar to a `Hash` but all the `Symbol` keys are going to be `Strings`.

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you, your answer is the best (albeit there is a bit typo, it should be `Foo.colors.key(1)`).

Answer (score 2):

Foo.colors returns a hash:

```
{:red => 0, :green => 1, :blue => 2}
```

You can invert the hash to get the indexed value

```
Foo.colors.invert
# {0 => :red, 1 => :green, 2 => :blue}
```

Comment: Great way to use enums when the value of the is a number. 
I used it like that:

Products.categories.invert[@product.categories] 

and i got the name of the value and not the integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

```
class Fooo < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum colo: {red: 0, green: 1, blue: 2}
end
```